# cannot import name 'Celery' from partially initialized module 'celery' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, redis, django-celery

whatever i do it shows me this error "cannot import name 'Celery' from partially initialized module 'celery' (most likely due to a circular import)"
this is my structure in django SB is the project and main is the app that has all the models

```
.
└── SB/
    ├── main /
    │   └── tasks.py
    ├── SB
    ├── celery.py
    └── manage.py
```

I tried every structure possible this is my code for celery.p:

```
from celery import Celery
from main.tasks import send_subscription_ending_email
app = Celery('SB')

# Configure broker and backend connections
app.config_from_object('django.conf.settings')
# Optional: Configure additional worker settings


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "send_subscription_ending_emails": {
        "task": "main.tasks.send_subscription_ending_email",
        "schedule": crontab(hour="*", minute="0", day_of_month="*"),
        "args": ([specific_subscription_id]),  # Replace with actual ID
    },
}
from main.tasks import send_subscription_ending_email
```

tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Subscription  # Import your Subscription model here

@shared_task
def send_subscription_ending_email(sub_id):
    # Fetch the subscription object
    sub = Subscription.objects.get(pk=sub_id)

    # Check remaining days
    remaining_days = sub.remain

    if remaining_days <= 3:
        # Get user email and format message
        user_email = sub.author.email
        message = f"Hi {sub.author.username},\nYour subscription for {sub.provider} - {sub.tier} will end in {remaining_days} days. Please renew to continue enjoying your subscription benefits."

        # Send email using your preferred email sending library
        send_mail(
            subject="Subscription Ending Soon",
            message=message,
            from_email="your_sender_email@example.com",
            recipient_list=[user_email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

I am using Django==4.2.8 and django-celery-beat==2.5.0, celery==5.3.6, I am in windows 10 using redis up and running in Port: 6379

fixing it and runing the celery.py and tasks.py

Comment: Sometimes the simplest thing to do is just to import dynamically rather than at the top of your file. Efficiency then depends on how often that import gets executed, but it does defer the problem import until initialization is complete.